# How can I find if a memory location is free for mmaping?

Tags: posix, mmap

I really want to reserve a specific set of memory locations with the `MAP_FIXED` option to `mmap`. However, by default `mmap` will `munmap` anything already at those addresses, which would be disastrous.

How can I tell `mmap` to "reserve the memory at this address, but fail if it is already in use"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just omit `MAP_FIXED` then Linux will use the requested address if free. If the requested address is not free some other address is used, in which case you can use `munmap`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [`mincore(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mincore.2.html)

This will be non-thread safe, unfortunately. Another thread might allocate that region after you check region status, but before you execute `mmap`.

If you need to reserve a memory area, just create anonymous private mapping with `PROT_NONE`. Later you can put different mappings on top of it using `MAP_FIXED`.

EDIT: Looks like `mincore` behavior is going to [change](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=574823bfab82d9d8fa47f422778043fbb4b4f50e) in Linux 5.0 due to the fact that it can cause information leak ([CVE-2019-5489](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2019-5489)):

> So let's try to avoid that information leak by simply changing the
>   semantics to be that mincore() counts actual mapped pages, not pages
>   that might be cheaply mapped if they were faulted (note the "might be"
>   part of the old semantics: being in the cache doesn't actually
>   guarantee that you can access them without IO anyway, since things
>   like network filesystems may have to revalidate the cache before use).

Vulnerability description can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.01161.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at that. If you want to know why I need this, it's because there is a bug in glibc's memmove, when you have a memory allocation which crosses the 2GB memory boundary, so I want to "block out" the page just above and below the 2GB memory boundary, so none of my malloced blocks will lie there.

Comment: @ChrisJefferson I have updated my answer. Looks like you won't be able to use `mincore` since Linux 5.0.